# LC_DATA_IN_CODE in IOS binary

Tags: ios, binary, legacy, mach-o

I have a IPA file whose main binary contains a 0x29 load command, which is specified in an older version of loader.h as "LC_DATA_IN_CODE".

However when I try to do anything with the file (including using otool or codesign) I get error messages about "unknown load command".

I am going to talk to the person who gave me the IPA file, but before that I wanted to get some history for this command. Is it no longer supported and if so what version did it leave? Or was it re-added to a recent version of the OS? Would removing it harm anything?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried removing this command but now I get an error which says the symbol table is out of place.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting these messages is because your version of otool is outdated. Most of Apple's tools break on a load command they don't know, and DATA_IN_CODE (which is actually not that old) has been put to use in recent binaries. You might also fail on OS X binaries which use LC_SOURCE_VERSION or LC_MAIN, for the same reason. Mountain Lion's otool might fare better, or you can use jtool, instead.